# Xamarin Android video uses native player controls for youtube embedded videos

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an app that plays a youtube video when a proper link is given. Problem is, the app uses what is probably a native player that overrides the youtube one. Here is my current code:

```
if (newsVideo != "" && isConnected == true)
        {
            myWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.NewsVideo);

            int intDisplayHeight;
            var screenwidth = metrics.WidthPixels;
            intDisplayHeight = screenwidth / 2;

            string convertednewsVideo = newsVideo.Replace("=\"\\", "=\\");
            List<string> newsVideoLink = VideoParseHTML.ReturnVideoUrl(convertednewsVideo);

            foreach (string item in newsVideoLink)
            {
                string strUrl = item.Substring(1, item.Length - 2);

                string html = @"<html><body><iframe src=""strUrl"" width=""100%"" height=""videoHeight"" frameborder=""0"" ></iframe></body></html>";
                var settings = myWebView.Settings;
                settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
                settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
                settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
                settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
                settings.BuiltInZoomControls = false;
                settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
                myWebView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                string strYouTubeURL = html.Replace("videoHeight", intDisplayHeight.ToString()).Replace("strUrl", strUrl);

                myWebView.LoadData(strYouTubeURL, "text/html", "UTF-8");

            }
        }
```

This is what the player looks like:

[image: Current video player]

What I want is either force the application to use the youtube player or if that isn't possible, to at least remove the fullscreen button from the native player, as I don't want this functionality.

Thank you

Comment: I wonder how could you get the youtube video into an `iframe` without opening a new window? Youtube prevents the video url from being loaded inside an `iframe`.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT The video link is the embeded one, not the simple URL. It is `https://www.youtube.com/embed/***********`, not `www.youtube.com/watch?v=***********`. Youtube gives you the whole `iframe`, but the service I'm getting the url from strips it. So I have to put it back again. That part works.